# How to proceed further with the following inequality problem that can be used by the arithmetic and geometric inequality theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, fake-proofs

I am an Advanced level math student and we were given to prove the following inequality for homework,

**If $a,b,c,p,q,r$ are positive real numbers show that,
$(a^2+b^2+c^2)(p^2+q^2+r^2)\geq(ap+bq+cr)^2$**

I actually gave this problem a try and below is what I have done so far,

> By using the arithmetic and geometric inequality theorem we can obtain the following three results,
> $\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}\geq (\sqrt[3]{abc})^2------>(1)$ 
> $\frac{p^2+q^2+r^2}{3}\geq (\sqrt[3]{pqr})^2------>(2)$ 
> $\frac{ap+bq+cr}{3}\geq \sqrt[3]{apbqcr}------>(3)$ 
>
> From $(1)\times(2)$ we get,
> $\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(p^2+q^2+r^2)}{9}\ge(\sqrt[3]{abcpqr})^2------>(4)$
>
> By obtaining the square of the relationship (3), we get,
>
> $\frac{(ap+bq+cr)^2}{9}\geq (\sqrt[3]{apbqcr})^2------>(5)$
>
> From $\frac{(4)}{(5)}$ we get,
> $\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(p^2+q^2+r^2)}{(ap+bq+cr)^2}\ge1\Rightarrow (a^2+b^2+c^2)(p^2+q^2+r^2) \ge (ap+bq+cr)^2$

**Here, what I do not understand is, I know that we can not divide two inequalities by each other. So I know there must be a mistake in my proof when I did the $\frac{(4)}{(5)}$. So how can I get the correct proof without dividing the two inequalities? What is the correct way to obtain the given relationship?**

I would be really grateful if you can answer my question. Thanks.

Comment: Look up “Cauchy-Schwarz inequality”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't this be shown directly?

$(a^2+b^2+c^2)(p^2+q^2+r^2)  ≥  (ap+bq+cr)^2$

\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
a^2p^2 &+ &a^2q^2 &+ &a^2r^2 &+ &≥ &a^2p^2 &+ &abpq &+ &acpr &+\\
b^2p^2 &+ &b^2q^2 &+ &b^2r^2 &+ & &abpq &+ &b^2q^2 &+ &bcqr &+\\
c^2p^2 &+ &c^2q^2 &+ &c^2r^2 & & &acpr &+ &bcqr &+ &c^2r^2 &
\newline
\newline
       & &a^2q^2 &+ &a^2r^2 &+ &≥ &       & &abpq &+ &acpr &+\\
b^2p^2 & &       &+ &b^2r^2 &+ & &abpq & &       &+ &bcqr &+\\
c^2p^2 &+ &c^2q^2 & &       & & &acpr &+ &bcqr & &       &\\
\newline
       &  &a^2q^2 &+ &a^2r^2 &+ &≥ &2abpq &+\\
b^2p^2 &  &       &+ &b^2r^2 &  &  &2acpr &+\\
c^2p^2 &+ &c^2q^2  &  &       &  &  &2bcqr\\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{ccccc}
a^2q^2 &+ &b^2p^2 &≥ &2abpq\\
a^2r^2 &+ &c^2p^2 &≥ &2acpr\\
b^2r^2 &+ &c^2q^2 &≥ &2bcqr\\
\end{array}

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
q^2/b^2 + p^2/a^2 &≥ 2pq/ab\\
q' &= q/b\\
p' &= p/a\\
q'^2 + p'^2 &≥ 2p'q'\\
q'^2 - 2p'q' + p'^2 &≥ 0\\
(q' - p')^2 &≥ 0\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

For any two $3$-dimensional vectors $\textbf{a}$ and $\textbf{b}$, we have:

$$\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{b} = a_{1}b_{1} + a_{2}b_{2} + a_{3}b_{3} = \vert\vert \textbf{a}\vert\vert\ \vert\vert\textbf{b}\vert\vert\cos(\theta)$$

Where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors. Note that $\cos(\theta) \leq 1$.

Consider the dot product of two vectors $\textbf{p} = (a, b, c)$ and $\textbf{q} = (x, y, z)$. We have

$$\textbf{p}\cdot\textbf{q}= ax + by + cz = \vert\vert \textbf{p}\vert\vert\ \vert\vert\textbf{q}\vert\vert\cos(\theta)\leq \vert\vert\textbf{p}\vert\vert\ \vert\vert\textbf{q}\vert\vert = (a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2})(x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2})$$

This proves the inequality. It also gives us the equality case, namely $\cos(\theta) = 1$, or $\theta = 0$. This is equivalent to the vectors being parallel and pointing in the same direction, or:

$$\frac{a}{x} = \frac{b}{y} = \frac{c}{z} \geq 0$$

This is called the *Cauchy - Schwarz Inequality*, and it can be generalized to any number of arguments with this dot product method.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cauchy-Scwartz inequality:
$$(ax-p)^2+(bx-q)^2+(cx-r)^2 \ge 0, \forall x \in \Re$$
$$\implies (a^2+b^2+c^2)x^2-2(ap+bq+cq)x+(p^2+q^2+r^2) \ge 0 \forall x \in R$$
If $Ax^2+Bx+C\ge 0, \forall x \in R$, then the discriminant $A>0, B^2-4AC \le 0$, this gives
$$(ap+bq+cr)^2 \le  (a^2+b^2+c^2)(p^2+q^2+r^2).$$
Equality, holds when $a/p=b/q=c/r=k, k \in R$

Comment: It is “Schwarz”, not “Scwartz.” (Hermann Amandus Schwarz)